# Проблема с кодировкой в Node.js с движком представлений Pug

Tags: node.js

Есть обработчик get запроса на typescript, который просто отдаёт pug страничку с объектом.

```
import express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Главная страница' });
});

export default router;
```

вот код pug странички index.pug

```
extends shared/layout.pug
block title
  <title>#{title}</title>
block content
  <p> Welcome to #{title} </p>
```

код макета layout.pug

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    block title
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    include partial/menu.pug
    block content
    include partial/footer.pug
</body>
</html>
```

в ответе приходит страничка с вопросиками вместо русских символов соответственно частичные представления тоже содержать русские символы
[image: страница которую отдаёт сервер]

скрин с запросом
[image: запрос]

Как настроить сервер, чтобы браузер мог декодировать кириллицу?
Среда разработки Visual studio 2019. Пишу на typescript, вот код файла tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [ "es6" ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "charset": "utf-8",
    "emitBOM": true,
    "locale": "ru"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Проверьте что все файлы сохранены в кодировке UTF-8.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а как это сделать в студии?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=как+сохранить+файл+в+utf-8+в+visual+studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сделал всё тоже самое в VS code, кириллица отображается нормально, файлы компилируются в utf 8, так что это какие-то внутренние настройки самой студии.